# Put custom methods in Behave's environment.py

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, python-behave

I am attempting to put the custom method, that would send results of automated tests to JIRA, in the Behave's `environment.py`. It would be in `after_scenario()` or `after_feature()`. So I want it to send the results to JIRA after closing tests.

It seems that those methods in `environment.py` only take in the methods that are part of `context` class. Is that right? Is there any walkaround this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods are expected to have precise names and arguments, as seen in [Behave's API reference](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/api.html#environment-file-functions). However, nothing prevents you from calling your own method within these hooks.

Something like this:

```
def after_feature(context, feature):

    send_feature_results_to_jira(context, feature)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions in "environment.py" can have any parameter that you like them to have. Only the hooks have a specified signature (as any API function). Therefore, if the feature object is sufficient to your processing, you should avoid to require somebody to pass the context object, too.